# macOS Mojave -- Finder won't show favorites and can't drag new folders into favorites

Tags: finder

Something happened to Finder on my Mac.  It won't show the favorites I've selected (as per Finder->Preferences), and I am unable to drag any folder into the Favorites area.

I've included a screenshot to highlight the first problem I mentioned.

What do I need to do to regain this functionality?

[image]

Comment: Restart the Mac into Safe Mode, by choosing "Restart" from the Apple Menu, then holding the Shift key when you hear the startup chime. This accomplishes some low-level OS maintenance, and frequently can fix this sort of small-scale failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hover your mouse over the word "Favorites", you should see "Show" button.

Comment: That fixed the problem.